# numpy: why would you ever use multiply instead of matmul for matrix multiplication?

Tags: numpy, matrix

In numpy, to multiply two matrices, you use `np.matmul`. But there's also a `np.multiply` function which I used by mistake and was surprised when it gave an answer -- the docs say that `np.multiply` is actually element-wise multiplication. IE, "multiply" does what you'd probably expect if you had never taken linear algebra, but if you have taken linear algebra, you're surprised that's the default.

Multiplying matrices with `np.matmul` is extremely common for many applications, but what's a use case for when you'd want the element-wise multiply? I can't think of any use case where that's useful with two matrices, so I'm surprised numpy doesn't make "multiply" do the matrix multiplication. Why make the element-wise multiplication the "default" choice for that keyword? Is there a common use case for element-wise multiplication?

Comment: `a*b` is `np.multiply(a,b)`. Look for that in sample numpy code. numpy is used for a lot more that linear algebra.  Or in MATLAB compare the use of `*` and `.*` (which conforms to your concept of default).

Comment: FYI: See [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Comment: `matmul` does matrix product rules for the last two dimensions, but elementwise rules on the others.

Comment: I should add that because of `broadcasting`, `*` multiplication applies seamlessly to element wise multiplication by scalars and arrays with different numbers of dimensions (e.g. 2d and 1d).  Star is defined as matrix multiplication for `np.matrix` subclass (for wayward MATLAB users :) ), but new use of that class is discouraged.